# Allow user to enter DSL, rules or code?

Tags: python, compiler, dsl

I have a python library that allows me to define rules by chaining inputs and outputs of functions ( producer(grep(count( [print(),log() ] ))) 
This functions define a pipeline from left to right.

How could I allow users to define pipelines from a UI ?

I need to take a definition like for example "producer->grep->count->print,log" and interpret it so as to call the former code.

Do i need a parser? an AST ? What would be a good way to build the call sequence fron a representation of the code?

Comment: You need to document. BTW, making a DSL is hard, and get it interesting to potential users is even harder. Read [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)

Comment: You are fast approaching trying to make the programming equivalent of a perpetual motion machine. The mental facilities one needs to define your 'pipelines' and debug them are exactly the same as the skills one needs to be a straight up programmer, so you might as well just let them program your library in python itself, rather than building a half-baked [inner platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: _Do i need a parser? an AST?_ are you sure you know what these two things are and what the relationship among them is?

Comment: Even if you are proficient in writing parsers and interpreters, it would extremely difficult to come up with a DSL easy to learn and understand. Most likely your users won't bother.

Comment: The DSL is (or can be) python. And it would be limited to describing graphs of callable objects. Yes, I know what they are, I'm looking for views on how to implement them. BPM editors are a case where the input to the runtime is a DSL (in XML) and that instantiates a graph of related objects, properties and conditions in runtime. Sort of that is what I want to build.

Comment: then use eval, exec, and similar python functions.

Comment: @whatsisname that would be dangerous (or would require sandboxing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the intended audience:

- **Are they programmers themselves or not?** If they are, then providing an API  will be the easy way. You can also provide a DSL, but be wary that specifying and implementing a language might not be a trivial task and you can't actually go and change the syntax at every release. Bending the syntax of a programming language into a DSL might or might not work and, most importantly, might add uneeded complexity.
- **Are they accustomed to writing batch scripts or not?** If they aren't, then you can forget a DSL, unless they are asking for it.

You don't actually know? What about some visual block programming backed by an API in your scripting language of choice? You could try [Google Blocky](https://developers.google.com/blockly/):

[image: blocks]

Comment: The intended audience could even code python statements. I only need a way to express a pipeline (like a bash command `<file sort | uniq | wc -l` or something like open().realines().sort().othermethod() but also with splits). The problem is going from a string "sort | uniq" to real objects in memory of class `sort` and `uniq`. I guess there are known best practices, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but also no just `eval()` user input because that would be dangerous.

Comment: Blocky is very interesting as input. I don't want to execute code directly though.  I need to either parse the generated code or sandbox it.